# MAP in PyMC is giving unexpected error

Tags: python, distribution, pymc, mcmc, multinomial

I don't understand why MAP is giving error where as MCMC works fine in the same scenario?
I am writing below the relevant part of code.

`tau = Uniform('tau', lower=0.01, upper=5, doc='tau')
 rv = [ Multinomial("rv"+str(i), count[i], prob_distribution[i], value = data[i],          observed =True) for i in xrange(0, len(count)) ]
 M = MAP([rv, tau])
 M.fit()
 tau_hat = M.tau.value()`

**Error: AttributeError: 'MAP' object has no attribute 'tau'** (for the last line M.tau.value())

On the other hand if I use MCMC in place of MAP, it works fine :

`m = MCMC([tau, rv])
 m.sample(iter = 500)
 print m.trace('tau')`

I want the point estimate of tau at which posterior has max probability and compare it with Bayesian prediction (for which I use MCMC)

Some information about variables:

prob_distribution is a deterministic function which, given tau and some other information returns a list of predictive probability distribution for each game. I have around 200 games, so prob_distribution is a list of 200 lists (each containing probability distribution over actions for that game eg `[0.4, 0.4, 0.2]`) Similarly count is a list of 200 numbers, count[i] denotes number of times i`th` game was played. data[i] is the observed information for i`th` game eg if data[i] = `[10 10 6]`, count[i] will be 26

**Additional note**

If I include the following line:

`model = Model([rv, tau])`

then Irrsepective whether I use

`M = MAP(model)` or `m = MCMC(model)`

this gives an error as follows:

**TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string**

Can somebody please explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

In PyMC2, the MCMC object exposes model nodes as instance variables but the MAP object does not.  It could be worth filing a feature request with the pymc-devs.  You can get the MAP value of tau by replacing your final line with

```
tau_hat = tau.value
```

A complete, minimal example of this workaround is the following:

```
from pymc import *

count = [10, 10]
prob_distribution = [[.5, .5], [.1, .2, .7]]
data = [[2, 8], [2, 3, 5]]

tau = Uniform('tau', lower=0.01, upper=5)
rv = [ Multinomial("rv"+str(i), count[i], prob_distribution[i], value = data[i], observed=True) for i in xrange(0, len(count)) ]
M = MAP([rv, tau])
M.fit()
tau_hat = tau.value
```

Note that `tau` is not informed by the data in this model as written...

Comment: I want that tau should have that value which maximizes its posterior probability and hence I am using MAP but in your code, if I print the value of tau before and after using MAP, it's not changing. If it can't be done using MAP, is there some other way to do so ??

Comment: This is an issue with the model you have constructed, not the MAP optimization.

Comment: can ypu please suggest any better model wherein I can use MAP optimization ?
Agai , kindly provide a small working example, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea what you are trying to model, so no suggestions as to what you should change.  Good luck!